# Как сделать проверку блока?

Tags: javascript

я наконец разобрался, с блоками, теперь вопрос в другом, 
как сделать проверку блока, жму на кнопку, появляется правильный блок, жму на кнопу из другого блока, появляется тот же, потом перезагружаю страницу, жму на второй блок, появлется он же, жму на первый блок, появляется он же
вот код:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn2").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    var row = document.getElementsByClassName("first_more_row");
    row[0].classList.toggle('more_show');
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("more_item");
    items[1].classList.toggle('more_show');
};
```

Comment: ещё бы html-css увидеть. и вообще хотелось бы воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Вот ссылка - http://euroingridients.monotone.by/catalog/milk/

Comment: css: .first_more_row {
    display: none;
}
.more_item {
    display: none;
    border:1px solid brown;
}

.more_item a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #a68057;
}


.more_show {
    display: block !important;
}

Comment: Делаю через wpBakery на wordpress